# The value of a single instance of object A is used by a lot of instances of object B

Tags: php, oop

I have been researching this all day, and I haven't found a good solution yet.

Before we get started: if you think the answer is "singleton", it isn't, singletons are not allowed in the project. Don't ask me why, cause I do not want to go in that discussion again. :)

So here goes (it is just an example):

- Object X of class A (only one instance is allowed to exist, but it needs to be created)
- Object X has a certain property like *$color = 'green';*
- All objects of class B that are created get the value of that property.
- When the property of Object X changes to *$color = 'red';* all new objects of class B that are created will get the new value
- If an object of class B is create when one of class A does not exist yet, the object of class A needs to be created

The question now ... how do I build my classes, and make sure only one instance of class A is created?

Am I making sense?

Comment: Dependency Injection of Object X into Object B

Comment: There's no "object B", there is _class_ `B`. PHP won't be very good at injecting a dependency into a _class_. You'll have to pass the `X` instance into _every_ instantiation of class `B`.

Comment: Seems that what you want is impossible to achieve. You don't want singleton, you don't want a static attribute to store color, yet, you want to guarantee that no more than one instance of that exists. Then, you can try save this data in a DB, a file, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the first created instance of `X` in a static property of the `X` class, like so:

```
class X {
  static public $instance = null;
  public function __construct() {
    if (is_null(X::$instance)) {
      X::$instance = $this;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can refer to `X::$instance->color` in your `B::__construct()` constructor.

A better way might be to have a `B` factory, which you inject your `X` instance into, and have your `B` class expect the `X` instance as a constructor parameter:

```
class BFactory {
  protected $x;
  public function __construct($x) {
    $this->x = $x;
  }
  public function make_instance() {
    return new B($this->x);
  }
}
$factory = new BFactory($X);
$instance = $factory->make_instance();
```

Comment: But how is static property of the type X is different from having a singleton instance of X?

Comment: OP is not very clear as to _what_ exactly he means by "singletons not allowed". This way you still can have multiple instances of class `A`, though only one would be "magical" (you need to have some way to select which `A` instance you want to use as your template for `B` instances). In any case, OP says that "only one instance [of class `A`] is allowed to exist", so by definition class `A` is actually a singleton, they're apparently just not allowed to call it that :)

Comment: I agree it is not very clearly defined. I am proposing a more complex way but at the sen seem hitting the same issue.

Comment: Just to be clear, the architect who reviews the code will not allow singleton design patterns. Code will not be accepted. Not my decision.

Comment: You say "only one instance is _allowed_ to exist". This _is_ a singleton pattern, even in specification. You cannot implement this specification without your implementation being a singleton pattern as well. Without a more insight into _why_ your system architect has banned singleton patterns, it will be hard to give you an advice that would still sit well with your architect. In most cases, people opposed to the singleton pattern tend to replace it with a static class that never gets instantiated and you use its static methods directly.

Comment: +1 since this is the right answer! A single instance of an object is exactly the definition of singleton. If the reviewer declines the code, then HE should suggesst the (in his opinion) right code, not the SO community.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the purpose of your application is. Nevertheless you could use a static variable to keep track of your objects.

```
class A
{
    private static $instance_exists = false;
    private static $color = 'green';

    public function __construct() {
        if(self::$instance_exists) {
            throw new Exception('tried to create another instance of A');
        }
        self::$instance_exists = true;
    }

    public static function getColor() {
        return self::$color;
    }

    public static function instanceExists() {
        return self::$instance_exists;
    }

}

class B {
    private $color;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->color = A::getColor();
    }
}

A::instanceExists(); // check anywhere
```

Comment: OK, this is part of it. How do I check in class B if an (the) object of class A already exists? If not, it needs to create that instance.

Comment: I don't get why you want to check for this? You could create a public static function in A to check if an instance exists (I will edit the post). Please note that A::getColor() is called statically so you do not need an instance of A here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a kind of property change listener on the object X.

- Each object B registers with the object X to receive the notification if the `color` property has been changed. This can be done in the object B constructor.
- On the property change event, object X calls the "set property" like method for all objects B it retains in some internal collection.
- Object X is logically stored in some reference that may initially be null. If it is null, object B can create a new object X in its constructor.
- If object B wants to change the global color property on its own initiative, it needs to retain internal reference to the object A. Something must be done to prevent the endless loop of notification events (pass the event source (object B that changes the color) to the object X along with the color value, etc).

Unfortunately when the new instance of B is created, it must get a reference about the possibly existing X from somewhere. If this cannot be a global static field, maybe:

- Let's assume objects B like bacteria can only be derived one from another so they can pass internal non static reference. First instance must be created in some special way.
- Let's assume we create all objects B in some method/function where we can use a local variable to hold the X reference.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of some cool dudes and dudettes. :)

It is an elegant solution, not quite what I had in mind, but it does the trick. Please note this is just an example, there is more going on under the hood.

```
class A {
    public $color;
    function __construct($new_color) {$this->color = $new_color;}
}

class B extends A {}

$color = 'green';
$y[0] = new B($color);
$y[1] = new B($color);
$color = 'red';
$y[2] = new B($color);
$color = 'black';
$y[3] = new B($color);
```

Thank you all for your input and suggestions. It helped us a lot. Thanks ...

Comment: This cannot be the answer to your question, because now class `B` is absolutely needless. Create `A` objects instead and everything is fine. But: Everytime an object is created, you can put any color in the constructor, cause this is no longer determined by a central place (class `A`). If this is really the solution to your problem, your question was very misleading.

Comment: If _this_ is what you went with in the end, then your question is pretty much useless and does not even approach describing anything that you were trying to do.